# result_array() data in where clause in OR condition : Active records Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause, where-in

result_array() for a query gives the following :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) )
```

I want to use id=1 and id=4 in the where clause in the OR condition like the following :

```
$this->db->where_in('id',$query->result_array());
```

But the above causes error. Is there any direct way of doing the same?

Comment: because it has arrays within that array.

Comment: yes .. i get that what I am doing is erroneous. But id there a direct way to perform this ?

Comment: I have done it done there..check it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_column`

```
array_column($query->result_array(), 'id')
```

here is [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to it.

Comment: sadly this is only valid for PHP 5.5 i got 5.3

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $roleIdQuery->result_array();
$column = array_map(function($sub)
                           {
                               return $sub['id'];
                           }, $result);
```

I used this. Sadly.

Answer (score 0):

because it has arrays within that array.

```
  $ids=array();
  $resultArray=$query->result_array();
  foreach($resultArray as $result){
   $ids[]=$result['id'];
  }
```

$ids // this is what you need to pass now..

Comment: this means that i will need to create a temporary array and process that. I want to skip this step.

Comment: actually the result that you are getting is array of arrays, either directly get an array or extract what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you change your original query to use GROUP_CONCAT. Not an option in Active Record so would need to write your own SQL. something like

```
$query= $this->db->query('SELECT GROUP_CONCACT(id) AS ids FROM table WHERE condition=true');
```

Then you should be able to do

```
$this->db->where_in('id',$query->result_array()[0]['ids']);
```

Just noticed your on 5.3 so unfortunately that means this won't work you will have to do.

```
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Then pass in `$result[0]['ids']`